# New Journals on Springer Nature?

Tags: journals, springer

Springer Nature contains a large number of journals. It seems that the entry and the exit (or the archiving) of journals are dynamic.

How can I know about the recently added or new journals added to Springer Nature?

Comment: I guess they'll be happy to tell you if you ask them directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to [a newsletter type of e-bulletin](https://support.springer.com/en/support/solutions/articles/6000219796-receive-information-about-new-springer-nature-titles) that will keep you informed about their new titles.

Comment: They are not offering it right now. See [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/stay-informed-with-springer-alerts/54290).

Comment: Ok, I did not click that far. But this seems like an issue that will be dealt with in the forseeable future and once it is fixed this is a simple way to keep track of the new journals.

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyway!